# Dominating $|f|$ on a compact convex set

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I have the following statemant:

> Let $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ compact and convex set. Now, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus K,$ there is $f$ holomorfic on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $||f||_K<|f(z)|.$

where $||f||_K=\text{max}_{w\in K}|f(w)|$ and I was told that I can prove this directly, without Runge's theorem but i have no starting point. I have somehow to construct $f$ depending on $z$...

Comment: Yes!! thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $K\subset \{x+iy: x\le 0\}$ and $z=1.$ Can you do it in this case?

Comment: If I take $f(z)=e^z$ its ok because $|e^z|=e^x$ and if $x\leq 0$ then $e^x\leq1<e=e^z$

Comment: But how do I move to the general case ?

Comment: Suppose $a$ is the point in $K$ closest to $z.$ Then the line through $a$ perpendicular to the line through $a$ and $z$ has a special property, due to the convexity of $K.$ What is it?

Comment: Ou! That line splits the plane in two semiplanes such that $K$ is contained in one of them. Now I see that im in a similar case with the first case. How do i apply the first case?

Comment: Oh! I get it now! I just have to compose with a affine  automorphism, which is biholomorphism of the plane is such a way that $a$ is mapped to origin, $z$ is mapped to $1$, and i take a point on the separating line and i map it to $i$ such that this mapping has det positive (because i want to leave $K$ on the left side of the plane)